# How to pass updating javascript variable into form to controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 200,
        max: 2000,
        values: [ 800, 1200 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

});
```

The code creates a price range and a slider bar, price range slides as user moves bar.
I want to pass the min price and max price into the form like:

```
<%= form_tag laptops_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "amount", params[:amount] %>

<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
```

But when I do so, the "amount" is still coming blank when submitted. Any ideas why?

Comment: Good details! Very well formed question.

Comment: Thre eseems to be no problem at the first look. Can you please check whether your `amount` element in GUI is updated to required value?

Comment: I sense sarcasm from slm. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your input element has an id attribute (not just name attribue). #amount means nothing without the id attribute (however, you could use: input[name=amount], if that's the problem).